# Get request object in Request module

Tags: node.js, request

With the Node JS *request* module it is possible to get the response, but, is there any way of getting the request headers sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the official way of doing this is but there are several things that seem to work.

If you haven't bound the callback to another `this` value then it will just be the request, e.g.:

```
request.get(options, function() {
    console.log(this.getHeader('... header name ...'));
    console.log(this.headers);
});
```

You could also access the request using `response.request`:

```
request.get(options, function(err, response) {
    console.log(response.request.getHeader('... header name ...'));
    console.log(response.request.headers);
});
```

That second approach should work anywhere that you have access to the response.

I believe these are the relevant lines in the source code:

https://github.com/request/request/blob/253c5e507ddb95dd88622087b6387655bd0ff935/request.js#L940

https://github.com/request/request/blob/253c5e507ddb95dd88622087b6387655bd0ff935/request.js#L1314